# How to add custom Ubercart check rule?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

How can I add custom check rules when hitting the checkout button? For example, I'd like to limit the total quantity of products in an order <= 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [hook_order($op='submit')](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/hook_order).

Comment: what if I want to perform the checking earlier (e.g. when clicked `Add to cart` or `Update cart`), instead of after filling payment information?

Comment: @ohho The Ubercart Documentation Index (http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api) lists all the hook that Ubercart provides. If can't find one that is appropriate, you can add a callback to the form in hook_form_alter (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).